# OpenGL Renders texture with different color than original image?

Tags: c++, image, opengl, bitmap, textures

Why are these not displaying the same colors?

Original Image:

[image]

Plane with above Image as texture:
[image]

WTF is happening?
The original image is 100x100 pixels, made in paint and saved as a 24 bit bitmap.
Here is my opengl initialization code:

```
    _hdc = GetDC(_hwnd);

PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
ZeroMemory( &pfd, sizeof( pfd ) );
pfd.nSize = sizeof( pfd );
pfd.nVersion = 1;
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
pfd.cColorBits = 24;
pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
int iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat( _hdc, &pfd );
SetPixelFormat( _hdc, iFormat, &pfd );

_hrc = wglCreateContext(_hdc);
wglMakeCurrent(_hdc, _hrc);

GLHelper* helper = GLHelper::get();
helper->initialize(_hwnd, _hdc, _hrc);
changeScreenResolution(_settings.windowWidth, _settings.windowHeight,
    _settings.sceneWidth, _settings.sceneHeight);

// Initialize OpenGL Settings
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); // Enable Smooth Shading
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f); // Black Background
glClearDepth(1.0f); // Depth Buffer Setup
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enables Depth Testing
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST); // Really Nice Perspective Calculations

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); 
float globalAmbient[4] = {0, 0, 0, 1};
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, globalAmbient);
```

I use the library FreeImage, which looks pretty well tested and widely used.

Here is the image loading code:

```
//image format
FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif = FIF_UNKNOWN;
//pointer to the image, once loaded
FIBITMAP *dib(0);
//pointer to the image data
BYTE* bits(0);
//image width and height
unsigned int width(0), height(0);
//OpenGL's image ID to map to
GLuint gl_texID;

//check the file signature and deduce its format
fif = FreeImage_GetFileType(filename, 0);
//if still unknown, try to guess the file format from the file extension
if(fif == FIF_UNKNOWN) 
    fif = FreeImage_GetFIFFromFilename(filename);
//if still unkown, return failure
if(fif == FIF_UNKNOWN)
    return false;

//check that the plugin has reading capabilities and load the file
if(FreeImage_FIFSupportsReading(fif))
    dib = FreeImage_Load(fif, filename);
//if the image failed to load, return failure
if(!dib)
    return false;

//retrieve the image data
bits = FreeImage_GetBits(dib);
//get the image width and height
width = FreeImage_GetWidth(dib);
height = FreeImage_GetHeight(dib);
//if this somehow one of these failed (they shouldn't), return failure
if((bits == 0) || (width == 0) || (height == 0))
    return false;

//if this texture ID is in use, unload the current texture
if(m_texID.find(texID) != m_texID.end())
    glDeleteTextures(1, &(m_texID[texID]));

//generate an OpenGL texture ID for this texture
glGenTextures(1, &gl_texID);
//store the texture ID mapping
m_texID[texID] = gl_texID;
//bind to the new texture ID
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_texID);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

//store the texture data for OpenGL use
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, level, internal_format, width, height,
    border, image_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bits);

//Free FreeImage's copy of the data
FreeImage_Unload(dib);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bitmaps are stored BGR (blue-green-red).  Your loading code is loading it as RGB (red-green-blue).  This is flipping your red and blue channel.

Use `GL_BGR` for the `format` parameter of `glTexImage2D`.

Comment: +1 I suppose looking at the picture was enough to see the channels were swapped ;-) – Alexandre Jasmin 5 mins ago

Comment: I'm pretty sure everyone who has ever loaded a bitmap has seen this at some point and had the same question (myself included) ;)

Comment: A simple inspection also reveals that the bitmap is being rendered upside down.

Comment: I can not find GL_BGR, but I use GL_BGE_EXT instead. It works! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you're loading your bitmap or what pixel format you're telling OpenGL to use, but you're red and blue channel are being swapped. AFAIK bitmaps store pixels as BGR, so make sure when you load the bitmap as BGR and not RGB.