# Why do the textured image colors are not the same as the origin?

Tags: java, c++, opengl, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL (OpenGL for Java) library for texture mapping.
Here is the code to read Image from file:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(url));
```

The code for getting Data Raster (Pixels of image) as byte array:

```
DataBufferByte imageByteBuffer = ((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer());
byte[] bytePixels = imageByteBuffer.getData();
```

Now the code of creating and putting the "bytePixels" array in byte buffer:

```
pixels = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(bytePixels.length);
pixels.put(bytePixels);
pixels.flip();
```

Here for binding all of that to buffer:

```
id = GL11.glGenTextures();
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
GL11.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

***The problem is, the colors of image textured aren't as the original image colors!!***

Original Picture:

[image]

Textured image:

[image]

---

This answer to [OpenGL Renders texture with different color than original image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093190/opengl-renders-texture-with-different-color-than-original-image), can't solve this issue, because `GL_BGR` is not valid in [lwjgl Class GL11](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html)!

Comment: *"The problem is, the colors of image textured aren't as the origin image?"* - What is the difference?

Comment: @Rabbid76 the difference is shown above in the Post !!

Comment: The issue is that the red and blue color channel are swapped. Is this OpenGL or OpenGL ES? Which OpenGL version do you use?

Comment: Most likely, your image is in `BGR` format. Just try `GL11.GL_BGR` in the `glTexImage2D()` call.

Comment: @Jaa No, in this version of OpenGL there is no `GL_BGR` format. See [Class GL11](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the red and blue color channel are swapped.

At OpenGL there is the possibility, to use the `GL_BGR` format, which specifies a internal format where the color channels are swapped (in compare to GL_`RGB`).

See [OpenGL 4 Refpages - `glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)
and [OpenGL Renders texture with different color than original image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093190/opengl-renders-texture-with-different-color-than-original-image).

At OpenGL ES you have to manually swap the red and blue color channel, because the internal format `GL_BGR` is missing.

See [OpenGL ES 3.0 Refpages - `glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)
and [lwjgl - `class GL11`](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html).

```
pixels = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(bytePixels.length);
pixels.put(bytePixels);
pixels.flip();
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 3) {
    byte t = pixels[i];
    pixels[i] = pixels[i+2];
    pixels[i+2] = t;
}
```

---

Another possibility would be given in OpenGL ES 3.0 or by OpenGL extension [`EXT_texture_swizzle`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_swizzle.txt):

Since OpenGL ES 3.0 you can use the texture swizzle parameters to swap the color channels. See [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexParameter.xhtml):

> `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_R`
>
> Sets the swizzle that will be applied to the r component of a texel before it is returned to the shader. Valid values for param are `GL_RED`, `GL_GREEN`, `GL_BLUE`, `GL_ALPHA`, `GL_ZERO` and `GL_ONE`. If `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_R` is `GL_RED`, the value for r will be taken from the first channel of the fetched texel. If `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_R` is `GL_GREEN`, the value for r will be taken from the second channel of the fetched texel. ...

This means the color channels will be swapped when the texture is looked up, by setting the following texture parameters to the texture object:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_R, GL_BLUE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_B, GL_RED);
```

The relevant part in the specification can be found at [OpenGL ES 3.0.5 Specification; 3.8.14 Texture State; page 162](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf)

To check if an OpenGL extension is valid, [`glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es1.1/xhtml/glGetString.xml) can be use, which returns a space-separated list of supported extensions.

See alos [android bitmap pixel format for glTexImage2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705921/android-bitmap-pixel-format-for-glteximage2d).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Because i use "LWJGL", i did not find either GL_BGR format nor GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE so i used your swapping code to swap between Red and Blue.

thanks a lot..